# C# .NET 6 IText 8 Fill rectangle with back color

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation

I just can't find how to do the following:

```
private void DrawOutSideFrame(ref PdfCanvas gfx)
{
    iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle Rectangulo = new(X, Y, RSize.X, RSize.Y);
    gfx.Rectangle(Rectangulo).SetFillColor(color).Fill(); 
}
```

I just want to create a rectangle with a color. Doing this it also change the color of the text on the page.

I had tried to find answers over the net but none seems to just fill a rectangle and nothing else...

Thanks in advance

ANSWER

```
private void DrawOutSideFrame(ref PdfCanvas gfx)
{
     gfx.SaveState();

    iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle Rectangulo = new(X, Y, RSize.X, RSize.Y);
    gfx.Rectangle(Rectangulo).SetFillColor(color).Fill(); 

    gfx.RestoreState();
}
```

Comment: What does your code instead of what you want it to do?

Comment: It also changes the color of the text of the page instead of just fill the rectangle

Comment: Well, you set the fill color, and text usually is drawn by filling outlines. So if your `PdfCanvas` has been added *before* the existing page content streams, that behavior is to be expected. You have to restore the original fill color after your `Fill` call.